# what is the difference between 'value' => 'accept', and 'checked' => TRUE, when using function form_checkbox()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I want to set my checkbox to be automatically unchecked when my webpage loads. I am using the function form_checkbox() which has these parameters if you use an array to give the checkbox your desired properties.

```
$data = array(
'name'        => 'newsletter',
'id'          => 'newsletter',
'value'       => 'accept',
'checked'     => TRUE,
'style'       => 'margin:10px',
);

echo form_checkbox($data);
```

which parameter in my array do I alter so that when my page loads for a user the checkbox is unchecked and then the user would have to check the checkbox for that checkbox to become true?

Comment: Did you try ´'checked' => FALSE´?

Answer (score 0):

Try

set `'checked' =>  FALSE,` *will generate checkbox unchecked*

or you can even remove `'checked'=>,`  *without this attribute it's by default unchecked*

Answer (score 0):

Think about how the HTML will look:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="accept"
                                                  checked style="margin:10px" />
```

Now, this will result in a checked box, because `checked` is set.

If you don't want that, just set `checked` to `false`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="accept"
                                                          style="margin:10px" />
```

What do you know, it's not checked ;)